# return afterSave in model yii2

Tags: yii2

If there is one controller yii2 with one model in which, for example, the outline only:

```
class MyController class extends Controller {
    public function actionCreate() {
        $valid = $model->validate();
    }
}
```

Need the return from aftersave, which is a message indicating if the email was able to be sent or not, and all the attributes were inserted.

**afterSave in the model:**

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes) {
    if(!$this->isNewRecord) {
        try {
            Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                // email composition here
                ->send();

            return 'mail sent';
        catch (\Swift_SwiftException $exception) {
            return 'email undeliverable'. $exception->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Can the return from afterSave be accessed by the controller?

Answer (score 0):

No, you will not be able to access any of those messages, because:

1. In the controller you are calling `$model->validate()` and `afterSave()` will never be called. You would need to call `$model->save()`.
2. `afterSave()` is not supposed to return anything, so the value you are returning is lost. See the function definition in the official documentation [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#afterSave()-detail)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not gonna trigger the afterSave event with your code. [\yii\db\BaseActiveRecord::afterSave](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/BaseActiveRecord.php#L898) is being triggered in 2 places

1. [\yii\db\BaseActiveRecord::updateInternal](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/BaseActiveRecord.php#L747)
2. [\yii\db\ActiveRecord::insertInternal](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/ActiveRecord.php#L488)

and if you take a look at [\yii\base\Model::validate](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/Model.php#L337) you'll see that afterSave isn't calling in here.